# how to add arbitrary widgets to a Canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, pysimplegui

I'm trying to build a GUI to tag files using PySimpleGUI. Underneath the main preview widget I want to put a widget to display current tags. I've made a `TagWidget` which subclasses `sg.Column` and contains an `sg.Text` for the tag name and an `sg.Combo` for the current value and suggested alternatives:

```
class TagWidget(_Widget, sg.Column):
  ''' A Display for a `Tag`.
  '''

  @typechecked
  def __init__(self, tags: TagSet, tag_name: str, alt_values=None):
    if alt_values is None:
      alt_values = set()
    self.tags = tags
    self.tag_name = tag_name
    self.alt_values = alt_values
    layout = [
        [
            sg.Text(tag_name + ("" if tag_name in tags else " (missing)")),
            sg.Combo(
                list(self.alt_values),
                default_value=tags.get(tag_name),
            )
        ]
    ]
    super().__init__(layout=layout, finalize=True)
```

The difficulty I have is making a widget to display several of these. I don't want a grid because the tag+value is very variable width. Ideally I'd use something like a canvas, or a pane containing a canvas, with a collection of tag widgets inside it. Ideally it would have a line-like flow.

I made a successful canvas with just text for each widget using `create_text()`. I could proceed with that and redraw as tags were edited, but I'd like to use my compound tag widget instead of flat text.

So... every PySimpleGUI widget has a `.Widget` attribute pointing at the underlying Tk widget. The canvas `.create_window` method looks like it should accept a Tk widget. However, until my compound Tag widget is rendered there is no `.Widget` to pass to `.create_window`, and it can't be rendered until the canvas is rendered.

My current (nonworking) attempt looks like this:

```
  def set_tags(self, tags):
    super().set_tags(tags)
    canvas = self.tk_canvas
    canvas.delete(canvas.find_all())
    for tag in self.tags:
      X("TagsView_Canvas.set_tags: add tag=%s", tag)
      tagw = self._get_tag_widget(tag)
      X("tagw = %s", tagw)
      X("tagw.Widget = %s", tagw.Widget)
      canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=tagw.Widget)
      X("added canvas window")
```

Of course, at this point `tagw.Widget` is `None` and nothing gets created.

Is there a clean way to prepare my compound tag widget so that I can apply it to the canvas? Should I be doing this another way?

*Amendment*

Looks like a comment is too constrained in formatting. Following up to Jason's example code, what I'm trying to do is make a new widget later in the programme and add it into the canvas (or graph, I do not mind which). I've been fiddling with Jason's main loop, doing a new iteration by clicking one of the buttons. I have not managed to add an additional widget to the graph, at least nothing visible.

Using an `sg.Text` as a simple example, I'm using this in his main loop:

```
while True:

  print("window.read...")
  event, values = window.read()
  print("event", event)
  if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
    break
  print(event, values)

  G = window['-GRAPH-']
  print("graph =", G)
  new_text = sg.Text("foo")
  layout[0][1] = new_text
  print("dir(graph)", dir(G))
  window.finalize()
  print("new_text.Widget =", new_text.Widget)
  graph.create_window(
      width // 4, height // 2, anchor=sg.tk.CENTER, window=new_text.Widget
  )
```

The current version (above) does not seem to initialise `new_text` widget, so `new_text.Widget` is still `None` and `graph.create_window` seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no method provided to add new element into layout, but `window.extend_layout`. It add new row into layout, but it does not work in `graph.Widget.create_window`.

A simple Demo code to show how to move `sg.Column` into a `sg.Graph`, remember that `sg.Graph` and `sg.Column` should be put under same row when layout.

```py
import io
import base64

from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg


sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

bg = 'green'
column_layout = [
    [sg.Text("Hello World", key="-LABEL-")],
    [sg.Button('Hello'), sg.Button('World')]
]

width, height = size = (320, 240)

buffer = io.BytesIO()
image_data = base64.b64decode(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LAUGH)
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
new_img = im.resize(size, resample=Image.CUBIC)
new_img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
im_b64 = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())

layout = [
    [sg.Graph(size, (0, 0), size, background_color=bg, key='-GRAPH-'),
     sg.Column(column_layout, background_color=bg, key='-COLUMN-')],
    [sg.Button('New')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
graph = window['-GRAPH-']
column = window['-COLUMN-']
figure = graph.draw_image(data=im_b64, location=(0, height))
graph.Widget.create_window(width//2, height//2, anchor=sg.tk.CENTER, window=column.Widget)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'New':
        new_element = sg.Text("foo")
        window.extend_layout(column, [[new_element]])

window.close()
```

[image]

It looks like not so good for the background_color of `sg.Canvas` will mask the background.

Comment: Thank you for that example. What I'm trying to do is add new widgets to the canvas (or graph) after it is prepared. So I want to prepare a new instance of my TagWidget and place it in the graph or canvas. Hacking your script has achieved nothing so far.  Currently the main loop is this:
```
while True:
  event, values = window.read()
  if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
    break
  G = window['-GRAPH-']
  new_text = sg.Text("foo")
  layout[0][1] = new_text
  window.finalize()
  graph.create_window(
      width // 4, height // 2, anchor=sg.tk.CENTER, window=new_text.Widget
  )
```

Comment: There's no method provided to add new element into layout, but `window.extend_layout`. It add new row into layout, but it does not work in `graph.Widget.create_window`. update code.